# How to handle clicked div and slide up its neighbor

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

Trying to make a slide down items. Everything works fine with one item. But i need to add multiple items and they all opens. I need to handle the click and open only one.

http://jsbin.com/xaxeregu/5/edit

**JQUERY:**

```
$('.faqTitle').click(function () {
    $('.faqAnswer').slideToggle('fast');
});
```

**HTML:**

```
<div class="faqItem">
    <div class="faqTitle">Here is my title</div>
    <div class="faqAnswer">here is an answer here is an answer here is an answer here is an answer here is an answer here is an answer here is an answer here is an answer</div>
</div>
<div class="faqItem">
    <div class="faqTitle">Here is my title</div>
    <div class="faqAnswer">here is an answer here is an answer here is an answer here is an answer here is an answer here is an answer here is an answer here is an answer</div>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
.faqItem {
    background-color: white;
}
.faqAnswer {
    display:none;
}
body {
    background-color: grey;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You 're targeting `.faqAnswer` only which will target all the divs with the class name `.faqAnswer` but if you want to target the next occurrence of the resultant target, you may target it with `$(this)` where `$(this)` refers to clicked [current] element.

Try this,

```
$('.faqTitle').click(function(event){
  $(this).next(".faqAnswer").slideToggle('fast');  
});
```

**OR**

```
$('.faqTitle').click(function(event){
  $(this).closest('div.faqItem').find('.faqAnswer').slideToggle('fast');
});
```

### [**Demo**](http://jsbin.com/xaxeregu/6/)

**Docs**

- [`next()`](http://api.jquery.com/next/)
- [`closest()`](http://api.jquery.com/closest/)

Answer (score 2):

You can get the parent of the element clicked, and then use find to find its children.. might be good solution incase your html changes, you can use `.parents('.faqItem')` instead.

```
$('.faqTitle').click(function(event){
  $(this).parent().find('.faqAnswer').slideToggle('fast');
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Try

```
$('.faqTitle').click(function() {
  $(this).next('.faqAnswer')..slideToggle('fast')
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
$('.faqTitle').click(function(event){
  $(this).next(".faqAnswer").slideToggle('fast'); 
});
```

Use   [**`next()`**](http://api.jquery.com/next/) to find the next faqAnswer

### [Demo Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/H4amc/)

Answer (score 2):

replace this line of code

```
$('.faqAnswer').slideToggle('fast');
```

with

```
$(this).parent().find('.faqAnswer').slideToggle('fast');
```